# Entity Framework Core Code First mapping to entity from multiple entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I've run into a bit of a problem building up my database using Entity Framework Core - Code First, which I know can easily solved but I'm pressed for time.

I have a country entity as seen below:

```
public class Country 
{
    public int CountryId {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<State> States { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a State entity like this:

```
public class State 
{
    public int StateId {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CountryId {get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country {get; set; }
}
```

My problem is how to map to a Country and State in my Address entity.

```
public class Address 
{
    public int AddressId {get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason, this setup allows me to select a countryId from a select list in my view, and save an address. However, the state field does not save even though while debugging I see that the stateId is actually passed to the controller action and ModelState is valid.

After saving through my DbContext, I see that the stateId value is never saved.

### Additional Detail

I didn't mention that I was using AutoMapper because I didn't think it was relevant to the issue but now I've realized that isn't true. My Address entity is actually a child of a Profile entity and I was trying to save the entire profile thinking AutoMapper could handle the FK in the the child entity but apparently it can't

### Solved

After changing my approach several times with no positive results I decided to save the Address entity separately from the Profile entity and now the Address.StateId field updates as it should.

If anyone has answers on how to properly map child entities in AutoMapper I would really appreciate that info.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add your entity configuration, and example code where you attempt to set the state and country on the new address. Setting FK fields where you have references defined can be problematic. Additionally, the collection of States in your Country entity should be marked virtual.

Comment: The entity model shown has cycle / redundancy: Country -> State -> Address and Country -> Address. From database POV it's better to remove `CountryId` FK from `Address` table. The `Country` can be obtained via `Address.State.Country`.

Comment: @StevePy I haven't configured these entities through Model Builder. The collection of states is actually virtual, I just missed that in my post.

Comment: @IvanStoev You're right, that's the error I've been getting. I've now removed the Country from the address, but now I get a foreign key constraint error for StateId when trying to add an address.

Comment: If they aren't configured by Model builder, and don't have attributes, then EntityTypeConfiguration? I'm not sure how far EF Core goes in terms of convention for entity config, but when it doubt go explicit. It helps if you outline what you have done, rather than what you haven't. ;)